# Installing boost 1.52 with VS2012

Tags: c++, boost

I followed these instructions to install boost and to compile all libraries:

https://www.quantnet.com/threads/tutorial-quantlib-boost-installation-in-visual-studio-2012.11891/

> Boost Installation The Boost library can be downloaded here.
>   Currently, the latest version available is Boost 1.52.0. You can build
>   boost by following the instruction here.
>
> Alternative you can download
>   a pre-built lib from here. Once downloaded, copy the installer into
>   the Boost 1.52.0 folder and run it. Rename the folder to lib once
>   done.

So I downloaded boost 1.52, then copied that to C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\

I then downloaded the 1.52 64 bit installer and once downloaded, pasted that to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_52_0\boost_1_52_0\

I executed the installer- it said "extracting" and then many library names.

I then renamed the last folder to lib, so that I had:

C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_52_0\lib\

In my VS2012 I then added the previous directory to my project. The project then starting parsing through the libraries and I had no linker errors. However, when building the project I still got:

> LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'libboost_date_time-iw-mt-gd-1_52.lib'

(The only usage of boost in my project is file_mapping and mapped_region)

Help?

EDIT: I am aware about some libraries needing to be compiled separately in boost. I thought the above was to achieve this? If not, could someone please advise how because this really becomes a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost has some libraries (most of them) used as source headers (.h files) that do not need to be pre-compiled, but there are also some libraries that need to be pre-compiled (.lib files). You can either download the libraries pre-compiled from the Boost website (http://www.boostpro.com/download/), although you might get some older versions from there, or compile them (the latest version or any of those available you want) on your own, although please have in mind that this might take some time, depending on your computer specs. See here for more: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html.

After downloading the "normal" boost package, put the folders/files extracted on a folder and then assocciate it in VS2012 by putting the folder path in

*(YourProject > Right-Click > Preferences >)General > VC++ Directories > Include Directories*.

Then download and install the pre-compiled libraries (extract them on a folder) and then associate this folder with the VS, in

*(YourProject > Right-Click > Preferences >) Linker > General > Additional Library Directories*.

Of course, as mentioned before, you can also compile the packages you want, and then associate them with Visual Studio the same way.

Comment: I thought that was the whole point of pasting the "installer" in to the boost 1_52_0 folder and executing, to compile those libraries? If not, can you please help me achieve this? and why does it complain when I am not using such a library in my project?

Comment: Those libraries don't come precompiled with the package. You can either download them pre-compiled or compile them on your own, to have those .lib files. Please look again on my answer, I have updated it.

Comment: Am I ok using boostpro 1.52 for VS2012? It only lists up to VS2011 and Boost version 1.51?

Comment: I am not sure about it, as I have passed 1.47 to VS2010 precompiled, and also compiled 1.54 for Windows. You can still try and see if it works of course.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what was the purpose of copying the "installer" to the boost folder? I don't see what that achieved in comparison to me just unzipping the boost files and then pointing at them from VS2012?

Comment: Just to mention I had the same problem with Link fatal error, till I set my VS2010 to work with those pre-compiled libraries.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37374/discussion-between-nick-l-and-user997112)

Comment: Hey, I may need to know how to resolve this in the future; don't forget to post an answer once a resolution is achieved. Thanks!

Comment: @JosuéMolina Ok, the answer is now updated, based on chat dscussion. I hope you find this one useful!